# Using LiveData/ViewModel with Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm going to first describe what I want to achieve:

I have an activity that contains a fragment. Now, based on some action the activity will call the FragmentManager and replace a brand new fragment of the same type.

In my fragment class, I have an associated ViewModel that I get.
In the fragment onCreateView() I subscribe to the LiveData component in the ViewModel.

I instantiate many of those fragments throughout the lifetime of the app but only one of them is active at any given moment as described above.

My question is, am I guaranteed that when calling `getSupportFragmentManager().replace(id, new MyFrag())` that it will stop observing changes from the LiveData in the fragment that is currently active (and about to be replaced) and rather the `new MyFrag()` will be the only observer?

My second requirement is that I need to know when the fragment was attached after calling `replace()` how do I ensure this? (note I don't want to override the onAttach() I want to know this after calling `replace`)

**Edit:** **I'm gonna describe my use case completely**

I need data to be initialized one time and observed by my Fragment.

Let me explain:

I have a Parent Activity that has a ViewModel which loads some data.
This data is needed by my Fragment and it is needed only for the first time the Fragment is created. What I do is I set up the observers in my Fragment which simply observers the changes in the LiveData of the parent activity. So right after I create my fragment I need that data to be initialized and **only once**, so hence I call the function that loads that data in the VM associated with my parent activity. But since my fragment isn't attached yet the data is simply lost because my observers only start to observe when the fragment is not only created but also attached.

Now you might say, so just initialize that data in the Fragments ViewModel constructor, but I can't do this because it depends on another crucial piece of data that only the parent activities VM has.

I hope I was clear, any guidance will help, thanks!

Comment: is there any reason why you want after replace() exactly? maybe i can help you with another solution. What are you tryin to achieve?

Comment: You shouldn't rely on whether you're using replace, or add to decide on crucial things in your app. I mean, you should ignore the fact that you have replace, as listening to data change from one fragment should not affect the logic in the other fragments

Comment: I updated my question further.

Comment: I don't understand how the data is *lost*? LiveData should keep the most recent value and call observers with it when they are added. Or is it because you're using some kind of live event class?

Comment: Ok but even if I change that LiveData multiple times before adding the Observer? Meaning, I understand if it is only one change but the LiveData is going through several changes before it gets observed.

Comment: @MosheRabaev You can't do that with LiveData, maybe look into RxJava's `ReplayRelay`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting the view model and subscribing to it in `onCreate`, you should do it in `onCreateView`, and use `viewLifecycleOwner` as the lifecycle owner. This ensures that when the view is destroyed, all observers are removed at the same time.

If you use `this` (the fragment) as the lifecycle owner, observers will only be removed when the fragment is destroyed. Assuming you use the back stack, replacing a fragment won't destroy it immediately. But the view is guaranteed to be destroyed.

As for the second question, I'm really not an expert in the fragment lifecycle but could you use `onCreate` or `onCreateView` here? What's the your case?

Comment: Good point, I said onCreate() arbitrarly I actually do get my VM's in onCreateView, btw I updated my question further.